# inheriting image properties when resizing using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to resize an image using PHP but I can't figure out how to get it to name the new image properly. When I look at my table for images in my databse, there is an entry with an ID, but no name.

Please let me know if there's anything else you need to see. As of right now I'm assuming I don't have the inputs correct for imagecopyresampled. When I try to echo the name for $formattedImage nothing happens. If I back it up one step further before using imagejpeg and echo the name for $blankImage, nothing happens either.

Here's my code.

```
 function chgSize($image, $width, $height){
    $name = $image["name"]; //this is displaying the file name correctly
    $temp = $image["tmp_name"];
    $imgContents = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($temp));
    $blankImage = imagecreatetruecolor(100,100);
       if(imagecopyresampled($blankImage, $imgContents, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 100, $width, $height)){ 
           $formattedImage = imagejpeg($blankImage, $name);
           $this->saveImage($formattedImage);
       }
 }


function saveImage($image){
        $newName = $image["name"];
        move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'], "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/images/" . $newName);
        mysql_query("insert into images VALUES('null','$newName')");
        echo "Stored in: " . "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/images/" . $newName;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI: `'null'` is **NOT** a null value. It's a string which contains the world 'null'. To insert an actual sql null, the word null must be specified WITHOUT quotes, e.g a bare `null`.

Your code is also vulnerable to SQL injection, plus your move_uploaded_file call is using user-provided data for the target filename, so you're allowing the remote user to specify ANY file ANYWHERE on your server to be scribbled on.

You've also apparently not checked at all if the upload succeeded or failed and are proceeding everywhere as if it has. Not good. Ditto for your insert query. Assuming a query succeeds is the worst thing you could possibly do. There's only one way for a query to succeed, and a few zillion ways for it to fail.

Comment: the `['name']` parameter in $_FILES is user-provided. It's trivial to manipulate, and since you're using it directly in a query, can be an injection vector. Never trust ANYTHING sent from client-side

Comment: imagecopyresampled will return true/false, which you're not capturing. it won't make the $new_img true/false. you're also passing in a GD image handle to the save function, which is not how thigns work. you need to use `imagejpeg($new_img, 'name_of_file')` to create a JPEG.

Comment: single quoted strings do not insert variables, `'$newName` will create a file whosename is `$newName`, not `whatever.jpg`. You probably want just `imagejpeg($new_img, $newName)`.

Comment: $new_img  v.s. $new_image... at some point, you're going to have to start looking at what you're writing instead of just parrotting errors on this site...

Comment: I updated my code above. I tried to clean it up a bit, but I'm still not getting it to work properly. If you're worried about sql attacks I made sure to check the image type above. Any other suggestions?